# Per node contact form, recipient from taxonomy

Tags: taxonomy-terms, webforms, emails

I'm attempting to build a conditional recipient contact form on D7 and I'm running into a few issues.

Here are my requirements. I have a Content Type called "Dataset", which has a Term reference field of "Departments". The "Departments" taxonomy has an additional field called "Contact Email", so by referencing or selecting a term from "Departments" you can also retrieve the contact email for that department.

I'm attempting to generate a contact form per node of the "Dataset" Content Type, that populates the recipient of the webform from the "Departments" taxonomy field "Contact Email". In addition, I would like to obfuscate the email in the list. I have seen the handbook guide for Webforms about creating a dropdown list and reading the recipient email from that, but that's not quite what I'm aiming for.

I've attempted a few different approaches, using Webforms with Rules, and I can't seem to make any progress. Can anyone provide guidance or best practices for this? Thanks!